# Convert UTF-16LE to UTF-8 in php

Tags: php, encoding, iconv

I use `iconv` php function but some characters doesn't convert correctly:

```
...
$s = iconv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $s);
...
$s = iconv('UTF-16//IGNORE', 'UTF-8', $s);
...
$s = iconv('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8', $s);
...
$s = iconv('UTF-16LE//IGNORE', 'UTF-8', $s);
...
```

I also try `mb_convert_encoding` function but can't solve my problem.

A sample text file: 9px.ir/utf8-16LE.rar

Comment: the string is an Arabic sentence and about half of the sentence characters didn't converted.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`iconv` [supports the `UTF-16LE` encoding](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/).

You can use it to transpose the encoding from `UTF-16LE` to `UTF-8`:

```
$result = iconv($in_charset = 'UTF-16LE' , $out_charset = 'UTF-8' , $str);
if (false === $result)
{
    throw new Exception('Input string could not be converted.');
}
```

See [`iconv`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php).

I'm just wondering if all code-points available in [`UTF-16LE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2) are available in [`UTF-8`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). But I assume that this should fit in your case.

---

**Edit:** I was not able to reproduce the problem on a box of my own, but on [another box](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GQ1TMz) I ran into this notice:

> Notice: iconv() [function.iconv]: Wrong charset, conversion from `UTF-16LE' to`UTF-8' is not allowed in ...

Looks like that not all `iconv` versions can actually convert `UTF-16LE` to `UTF-8`.

It might be a workaround to use [`mb_convert_encoding`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) instead, at least it was in this case ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/W4ry1v)):

```
$result = mb_convert_encoding($str , 'UTF-8' , 'UTF-16LE');
```

Comment: @ali mzm: Can't reproduce, that file works for me with the code example above.

Comment: @ali mzm: Looks like not all iconv versions support that, maybe you're getting this error? http://codepad.viper-7.com/GQ1TMz

Comment: @ali mzm: I added a `mb_convert_encoding` example which does the same as `iconv`.

Comment: no i didnt get the error. i get an string that some characters converted correctly and some not.

Comment: @ali mzm: Are you using `//TRANSLIT` or `//IGNORE`? If so, please don't do unless you've found the cause. If I try either with `iconv` or with `mb_convert_encoding` and *your* data, I can not reproduce the problem. See this demo, which has *your* data - do you see your problem as well in the output? http://codepad.viper-7.com/W4ry1v

Answer (score 0):

You should use `//TRANSLIT` or `//IGNORE` in the second argument of the function, which represents the **output charset**. You used it by mistake in the first argument.

Please, see more details and examples at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php